# "Invalid partition key" when making a REST call using Node.js to retrieve a single document from Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

## Bakground

I am trying to develop a demo that pulls a single document from Cosmos DB SQL API using REST calls. I have a database in Azure and this database has a  collection. This collection contains two objects at the moment. The collection was created with the partition key "/name". The code below works, if I want to retrieve a collection itself for instance. However, I need to get a document by using the document id from a particular collection. As I mentioned, I get a 200 response when it comes to a collection, but a single document request spits out "Partition Key 'name' or '/name' (or whatever as this point) is invalid."

## What I have tried

I've tried all sorts of ways how to correctly configure the header files. Currently, the two objects in the database look like this:

```
{
    "id": "test2",
    "name": "bla2",
    "_rid": "knQwAMkBmw4CAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/knQwAA==/colls/knQwAMkBmw4=/docs/knQwAMkBmw4CAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"140085d3-0000-0d00-0000-5cd760670000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1557618791
}
```

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "name": "bla1",
    "_rid": "knQwAMkBmw4BAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/knQwAA==/colls/knQwAMkBmw4=/docs/knQwAMkBmw4BAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"140079d3-0000-0d00-0000-5cd75e680000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1557618280
}
```

**These are pretty much my desired outputs.** I am at my wit's end honestly. I've been googling for hours and I just cannot get it right. The call is authorized. Can anybody point me to the correct direction please on how to correctly configure the Partition Key?

## Code

```cs
var request = require("request");
var crypto = require("crypto");

function getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb, resourceType, resourceLink, date, masterKey) {  
    var key = new Buffer(masterKey, "base64");  

    var text = (verb || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               (resourceType || "").toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               (resourceLink || "") + "\n" +   
               date.toLowerCase() + "\n" +   
               "" + "\n";  

    var body = new Buffer(text, "utf8");  
    var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", key).update(body).digest("base64");  

    var MasterToken = "master";  

    var TokenVersion = "1.0";  

    return encodeURIComponent("type=" + MasterToken + "&ver=" + TokenVersion + "&sig=" + signature);  
}

var mkey = '{my-master-key}';
var resourceType = 'docs';
var resourceLink = 'dbs/{MyDatabaseId}/colls/{MyCollId}/docs/test2';

var verb = 'GET';
var date = new Date().toUTCString()

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://{mycosmosdb}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{MyDatabaseId}/colls/{MyCollId}/docs/test2',
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
   Connection: 'keep-alive',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition': true,
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'x-ms-documentdb-PartitionKey': [ "name" ],
     'x-ms-date': date,
     'x-ms-documentdb-isquery': true,
     'User-Agent': 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client/1.6.0.0',
     Host: '{mycosmosdb}.documents.azure.com:443',
     'Content-Type': 'application/query+json',
     Authorization: getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb,resourceType,resourceLink,date,mkey),
     'x-ms-version': '2017-02-22',
     Accept: 'application/json',
      }

    };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

## Error output:

`{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Partition key name is invalid.\r\nActivityId: f73587d0-20d0-482f-9422-36c214e266d4, \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-05-11T23:53:34.4517344Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-05-11T23:53:34.4517344Z, Number of regions attempted: 1\r\n, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.2.0.0"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the value of `x-ms-documentdb-PartitionKey` header should be the value of the `PartitionKey` attribute in the document and not the name of the `PartitionKey`.

From the [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document) documentation:

[image]

To fix the issue, please change the following line of code:

```
'x-ms-documentdb-PartitionKey': [ "name" ]
```

to

```
'x-ms-documentdb-PartitionKey': [ "bla2" ]
```

And you should not get this error.

**UPDATE**

So I looked up the code in Node SDK and how it is passing the PartitionKey header. Essentially, the header value needs to be a string.

Please try with the following value:

```
 'x-ms-documentdb-Partitionkey': "[\"bla2\"]",
```

I just tried it and it worked fine for me.

Here're the headers I am passing in the request:

```
  {
    'x-ms-documentdb-Partitionkey': "[\"bla2\"]",
    'x-ms-date': date,
    'authorization': getAuthorizationTokenUsingMasterKey(verb,resourceType,resourceLink,date,mkey),
    'x-ms-version': '2017-02-22'
  }
```

Comment: Hi. I have tried that. Unfortunately, I get: "Partition key bla2 is invalid...". I am not sure what else should I try.

Comment: Can you get rid of `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` header from your request and try again?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully it should fix your problem. I was able to get the document details.

Comment: Yes! That's it! This is the correct answer. Thank you a lot.